# Sed works only without grouping

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file of the following format:

```
foo: ...
bar: ...
baz: ...
```

I want to delete all lines that start with `bar`, `baz` or `goo`. I could do a couple of seds in the following format:

```
sed '/^bar:.*$/d'
```

But I'd like to instead put all the possibilities in one. I thought this would work, but its not deleting the lines:

```
sed '/^(?:bar|baz|goo):.*$/d'
```

I also noticed that not even this works:

```
sed '/^(bar):.*$/d'
```

Which was surprising because I thought the capture group wouldn't actually change any behavior in the pattern matching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use extended regular expressions

```
sed -r '/^(bar):.*$/d'
```

And sed doesn't support perl regular expressions, so you should be using

```
sed -r '/^(bar|baz|foo):.*$/d'
```

without non capture group `?:`

Comment: On some systems you may need `sed -E` instead of `sed -r`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
sed '/^\(bar\|baz\|foo\):/d' file
```

Or with extended regex:

```
sed -r '/^(bar|baz|foo):/d' file
```